# Extend div height to document height

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to make extensible sidebars to the full document height without Javascript. I started to wrote some code to make this happen, but however, both div height are not extending after the viewport size.

Here is a small codepen of what is my problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpAzo. As you can see, if you scroll down, height of both sidebars are just set to viewport size which is weird because i set both `body, html, #sidebars` to `height: 100%;`.

Is there a way to extend to full page height without using Javascript ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set your sidebar height to 100% which gives it just a 100% of current browser size. Remove the height of your sidebar and remove also the html and body code.

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    color: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.left {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
}
.right {
    background-color: red;
    right: 0;
}
```

**DEMO HERE**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jfEhH

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but I want 100% height of the document (not browser), even if it has no more content. Example: Content of my left sidebar is 500px, the right sidebar should have 500px of height even if its content is only 200px. Is it possible without Javascript?

Comment: Then set the position of your left sidebar into fixed `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

If you set html and body to 100% height it will just be 100% of the window ( it's parent ) size. You need to set a specific height ( 3000px ) or 200% for example, which will be 2 times the windows height.

Answer (score 0):

Body tag on codepen by default have `margin`. Without margin all looks good.
http://codepen.io/suez/pen/zJhne

But in the future, i will reccomend you to use `overflow: hidden;` on body (combined with `margin: 0`), this will provide 100% confidence that all of your content always will be inside viewport (without any scrolling).

Edited: if you want to use more than 100% of viewport height for your site, then you need to use `position: fixed;` on sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the "height" attribute in your CSS style sheet to "auto", like as follows,

`sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height:auto;
    width: 100px;
    color: green;
}`

Don't worry about "sidebar.right" ,as u will see no red color on right side of your page. It will automatically show up  when you add up some content to it or just add few `<br />` tags.